# Why is the JSONObject(jsonString) constructor throwing an exception in my android app?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON object in my android application and I do so like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

the value of jsonString is:

```
  [{"pk": 1, "model": "mydb.user", "fields": {"username": "willyb", "password": "tao1", 
  "signup_date": "2011-11-28 09:15:58", "email": "wfbarksdale@gmail.com"}}]
```

Is there an obvious reason why this is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is a JSONArray, not JSONObject. (See [here](http://www.json.org/))

You should do:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject json = arr.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is an array. Try:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```